# supabaseClient.auth.session is not a function

Tags: next.js, supabase

I upgraded from Supabase v1 version to v2 version. But I getting error **"supabaseClient.auth.session is not a function"** everywhere. Anyone know why?

In Supabase v1 I converted supabase.auth.signIn function to supabase.auth.signInWithPassword .

Answer (score 3):

Is there someplace you retrieve the session? If so you would need to update from `const session = supabase.auth.session()` to `const {data: { session },} = await supabase.auth.getSession()` which is also highlighted in the upgrade guide: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/upgrade-guide

Comment: I'm not using it in my project at the moment but still getting this error.